# Swap two columns - awk, sed, python, perl

Tags: sed, awk

I've got data in a large file (280 columns wide, 7 million lines long!) and I need to swap the first two columns. I think I could do this with some kind of awk for loop, to print $2, $1, then a range to the end of the file - but I don't know how to do the range part, and I can't print $2, $1, $3...$280! Most of the column swap answers I've seen here are specific to small files with a manageable number of columns, so I need something that doesn't depend on specifying every column number.

The file is tab delimited:

```
Affy-id chr 0 pos NA06984 NA06985 NA06986 NA06989
```

Answer (score 128, accepted):

You can do this by swapping values of the first two fields:

```
awk ' { t = $1; $1 = $2; $2 = t; print; } ' input_file
```

Comment: That is so neat and elegant, thank you! I was hoping there would be a one-liner out there.

Comment: This answer is problematic with different sizes of columns and their separators. More extensible answer here http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31596/16920

Comment: actually it's not problematic with different number of columns, only with mixed separators: for example, if you have both tabs and spaces in your file, and you only want to separate ields by tabs, you need the `BEGIN{FS='\t'}` trick.

Comment: Using `-F '\t'` tabs are eaten away in the final output. Is there a way to preserve them?

Comment: OK, one has to specify `OFS=$'\t'` as pointed out by the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29532554/2247039) below. @perreal, perhaps it's worth it updating the answer with the additional parameter?

Comment: if you use: `awk '{ print $2, $1}' `

is the same :D

Comment: This was really helpful! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @A.Villegas That only prints the first two columns.

Comment: I'm surprised this answer is so upvoted. Certainly not "so neat and elegant", as wrongly stated above. As @A.Villegas pointed out, `awk '{ print $2, $1 }'` is neat and elegant, not an unnecessary variable swap. Sorry, had to downvote.

Comment: @cornuz, no problem, Note that your suggestion only prints 2 columns. OP wants to print all columns not just the first two.

Comment: @perreal, my bad, I hadn't noticed that. I would remove my downvote, but it doesn't allow me anymore. Sorry, next time I'll be more careful.

Comment: @Atcold  for sure! | sed 's/ /\t/'

Answer (score 26):

I tried the answer of perreal with cygwin on a windows system with a tab separated file. It didn't work, because the standard separator is space.

If you encounter the same problem, try this instead:

```
awk -F $'\t' ' { t = $1; $1 = $2; $2 = t; print; } ' OFS=$'\t' input_file
```

Incoming separator is defined by `-F $'\t'` and the seperator for output by `OFS=$'\t'`.

```
awk -F $'\t' ' { t = $1; $1 = $2; $2 = t; print; } ' OFS=$'\t' input_file > output_file
```

Comment: Super! I was missing the `OFS=$'\t'` parameter!

Comment: This approach can end up with tabs at the start of the line. Might not be the intended outcome.

Answer (score 13):

Try this more relevant to your question :

```
awk '{printf("%s\t%s\n", $2, $1)}' inputfile
```

Comment: This only prints the first two columns. Slightly more compact is `awk '{print $2 "\t" $1}' inputfile`.

Answer (score 6):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i 's/^\([^\t]*\t\)\([^\t]*\t\)/\2\1/' file
```

Comment: Perfect solution for us vim users.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the cut command? E.g.

```
cat myhugefile | cut -c10-20,c1-9,c21- > myrearrangedhugefile
```

Comment: I haven't, but I'll remember that for future use!

Comment: -c=characters ... so this does not exchange columns.

Comment: It will swap columns in the output file - try it for yourself

Comment: how can we do it without knowing the character count ? 
`cat myhugefile | cut -f2,1` gives the same output as `cat myhugefile | cut -f1,2`

Comment: You can output each column to an intermediate file. Something like: **cut -f2 myhugefile > piece1 ; cut -f1 myhugefile > piece2 | paste piece1 piece2 > myrearrangedhugefile ; rm piece1 ; rm piece2**

Answer (score 3):

This is also easy in perl:

```
perl -pe 's/^(\S+)\t(\S+)/$2\t$1/;' file > outputfile
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in Perl:

```
perl -F\\t -nlae 'print join("\t", @F[1,0,2..$#F])' inputfile
```

The `-F` specifies the delimiter. In most shells you need to precede a backslash with another to escape it. On some platforms `-F` automatically implies `-n` and `-a` so they can be dropped.

For your problem you wouldn't need to use `-l` because the last columns appears last in the output. But if in a different situation, if the last column needs to appear between other columns, the newline character must be removed. The `-l` switch takes care of this.

The `"\t"` in join can be changed to anything else to produce a different delimiter in the output.

`2..$#F` specifies a range from 2 until the last column. As you might have guessed, inside the square brackets, you can put any single column or range of columns in the desired order.

Answer (score 2):

No need to call anything else but your shell:

```
bash> while read col1 col2 rest; do 
        echo $col2 $col1 $rest
      done <input_file
```

Test:

```
bash> echo "first second a c d e f g" | 
      while read col1 col2 rest; do 
        echo $col2 $col1 $rest
      done
second first a b c d e f g
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe even with *"inlined"* Python - as in a Python script within a shell script - **but** only if you want to do some more scripting with Bash beforehand or afterwards... Otherwise it is unnecessarily complex.

Content of script file `process.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# inline Python script
read -r -d '' PYSCR << EOSCR
from __future__ import print_function
import codecs
import sys

encoding = "utf-8"
fn_in = sys.argv[1]
fn_out = sys.argv[2]

# print("Input:", fn_in)
# print("Output:", fn_out)

with codecs.open(fn_in, "r", encoding) as fp_in, \
        codecs.open(fn_out, "w", encoding) as fp_out:
    for line in fp_in:
        # split into two columns and rest
        col1, col2, rest = line.split("\t", 2)
        # swap columns in output
        fp_out.write("{}\t{}\t{}".format(col2, col1, rest))
EOSCR

# ---------------------
# do setup work?
# e. g. list files for processing

# call python script with params
python3 -c "$PYSCR" "$inputfile" "$outputfile"

# do some more processing
# e. g. rename outputfile to inputfile, ...
```

---

If you only need to swap the columns for a single file, then you can also just create a single Python script and statically define the filenames. Or just use an answer above.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` swapping ***sans temp-variable*** :

```
echo '777777744444444464449: 317 647 14423 262927714037  :   0x2A29D5A1BAA7A95541' |
```

> ```
> mawk '1; ($1 = $2 substr(_, ($2 = $1)^_))^_' FS=':' OFS=':'
> ```

```
777777744444444464449: 317 647 14423 262927714037  :   0x2A29D5A1BAA7A95541

 317 647 14423 262927714037  :777777744444444464449:   0x2A29D5A1BAA7A95541
```