# How to switch columns 5 and 6 in a file in Linux?

Tags: linux

How to switch columns 5 and 6 in a file in Linux?

I data samples as follows:

R950E03 111006 930226 910008 Resistant 1

R950E06 110917 950085 910043 Resistant 2

R950C09 110892 950085 910125 Resistant 2

R949B05 111101 870141 840409 Resistant 2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swap two columns - awk, sed, python, perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967776/swap-two-columns-awk-sed-python-perl)

Comment: Columns can be irregular  After moving the columns.                 R950E03 111006 930226 910008 1
 Resistant
R950E06 110917 950085 910043 2
 Resistant

Comment: R950C09 110892 950085 910125 2^M Resistant

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk.

```
awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $6, $5}' yourfile > tmp
mv tmp yourfile
```

Comment: Columns can be irregular After moving the columns.                             
 
R950C09 110892 950085 910125 2^M Resistant

Answer (score 0):

Use `cut` instead of `awk` if you want

Refer to

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/11967934/7188414

Regards