# Awk ordering of delimited string

Tags: regex, awk

I have string with "|" delimited fields:

```
name|phone|email|surname|house|street|
```

from code side, at the end of this string is "\n"
How can I reorder this string using awk saving delimiter?

`awk '{print $1,$4,$3,$2....}'` doesn't work it just deletes column.

Comment: You should mention `awk -F'|' {print $1,$2,....}'` and it should fly then since your Input_file(shown sample) doesn't look like having space as delimiter so mention its delimiter as per your input and it should work then.

Comment: setting -F delimiter only replaces delimiter with space. Even tried using begin with FS

Comment: Do you just need to [swap a pair of fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967776/swap-two-columns-awk-sed-python-perl)?

Comment: You also need to set  the output field separator `OFS`: `awk -v OFS="|" ...` or `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}`

Comment: @Jane, if you give like `-F'|'` it should set delimiter like `|` for all lines of Input_file.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Thanks, helped setting OFS, and don't know why, but setting -F '|' doesn't effect anything, but replacing... but -F'|' without space helped =\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk

```
$awk '{print $1,$4,$3,$2}' FS="|" OFS="|" file
name|surname|email|phone
```

Answer (score 1):

Set input and ouput field separator:

```
echo 'name|phone|email|surname|house|street|' |\
  awk '{print $1,$4,$3,$2,$6,$7}' FS='|' OFS='|'
```

Output:

```
name|surname|email|phone|street|
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to swap fields 2 and 4 via a temporary variable:

```
awk -F'|' '{ tmp=$2; $2=$4; $4=tmp } 1' OFS='|'
```